# Ability to change homepage on Wordpress using API

Tags: plugins, api, homepage, frontpage, headless

Is there any way to change a site's homepage (Settings -> Reading), via API? We're running a React app with a Headless WP 'backend', and I'd like to let users change the homepage of their sites though our app.

I searched but couldn't find a solution to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can change some settings via the REST API, but it doesn't look like the Home Page is one of them. At least, it doesn't seem to appear in the [REST API > Site Settings](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/settings/#update-a-site-setting) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't really change the whole homepage using API. Instead you could fetch different parts like Posts, Categories and display them using the API.